# How to open sitx files?

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format

I want to open a sitx file. I tried to open it using Unar and 7zip, but I did not succeed.

What is the right application to open sitx files?

Comment: As far as I know, it is a priority archive format with no Linux compatibility. You can use Windows or MAC and convert it to a linux compatible format. There is a bit of a discussion (with no solution) on the forums - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1595792 Similar , shorter discussions come up in a google search.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are [StuffIt](http://www.stuffit.com/) files. It appears to be a proprietary format and unpopular enough that <strike>none of the open source archivers have ever bothered to reverse-engineer it</strike> only one application ([see Sharath's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/501640/449)) has ever battled it.

The Unarchiver does only claim partial support. If the archive uses the more advanced features like encryption or JPEG compression, by all means give it a shot, but you'll likely need to fall back to one of these options, none of them great:

- Use a real copy of Windows or OSX along with StuffIt Expander. This could be in a Virtual Machine.
- Battle Wine to the death. Stuffit Expander uses the .NET framework v4 which seems to mean "it's just not going to work quite yet". [AppDb reviews seem to corroborate that](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9490).
- Find the person sending you such an obscure format and keep stroking their hair until they agree to send you a standard format like, you know, a Zip.

Comment: +1 for "Find the person sending you such an obscure format and keep stroking their hair until they agree to send you a standard format like, you know, a Zip."

Answer (score 13):

You can try 'The Unarchiver' http://unarchiver.c3.cx/ which claims to support decompressing .sitx

For installation, have a look at http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline

```
sudo apt-get install unar
unar archive.sitx
```